# ERROR in "size" argument must not be larger than 2147483647 (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting this error when trying to compile my angular 6 project during development and also when I'm trying to build for production.
Can't seem to find any solution to it.

Related search results talk about a server side being unable to load a file, but I'm not trying to load any file.

I've ran `npm cache clean --force`, I've deleted my node modules and reinstalled it. Still no change

Node version: v8.10.0
npm version: 6.7.0
Angular version: Angular 6

Comment: npm start -- --reset-cache can you try it? it's worked for me

Comment: Are you using file system to load a file programatically?

Comment: @FedeSc no. 


Apparently, my system was acting up and had cloned another folder into my project's directory without that folder being visible, hence the issue.